# Make sure nodejs express route can only be called once, until finished

Tags: node.js, http, express, request

My endpoint

```
POST example.com/user/transfer/
```

should not be able to be called by the same user until his earlier request has been processed. How do I do that?

**Ideas**

- Keep a request Nonce in the user table (database) and make sure it can only be used once.
- ?

I might be not wrapping my head around it the right way.

Comment: You need to keep state. Whether it's in the application, in-memory database or traditional database. What ever path you take depends on your use case. But one thing will remain the same your code needs to read/write this state and block or allow passed on it's value.

Comment: @Darkrum In my use case im using redis to cache a lot of stuff already, is it appropriate to store stuff like user_id somewhere and delete after the request has finished?

Comment: that's the only way. You could also in your client code keep state and stop it from making new requests till the previous request returns

Comment: @Darkrum not possible in my case. This is an important endpoint which should not be abused in any way. What about rate-limiting though?

Comment: So you're trying to protect against spam? Or is it important for this request to finish before another can be done(like syncing data) those are two entirely different requirements.

Comment: @Darkrum When this specific endpoint is called, it will then proceed to call a 3rd-party API which will do unreversable stuff. So from a user point of view it should not be possible for him to spam this endpoint twice and it getting processed twice.

This endpoint should only be allowed to be called once per user, until the processing has finished. Then the user may request again.

Comment: So then I will refer back to my first comment. You need to keep state and reject or allow based on the state.

Comment: @Darkrum how would I realize soemthing like this? https://redis.io/commands/exists maybe?

Comment: that's one way. request is made ->check redis exists -> set redis key -> wait for request to finish -> delete key on request completion.

Comment: @Darkrum thanks. Any resources to follow up on stuff like this? I mean I can ask more questions (not about this specific topic) but overall - best practices. Thank you btw.